# Can I use svg – code or file – or images in yml data files in jekyll?

Tags: jekyll

I have a loop that pulls data from a data file. I want one of the things it pulls to be an icon, either svg code or file, or an image file, whatever works.

Data file `example.yml`:

```
- title: Lorem title
  description: Lorem description 
  icon: [icon code or file?]
```

Loop example:

```
{% for item in site.data.example %}
<span>{{ item.icon }}</span>
<h3>{{ item.title }}</h3>
<p>{{ item.description</p>
{% endfor %}
```

Can this work somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could introduce a type:

```
- title: Lorem title
  description: Lorem description 
  icon:
    type: icon
    name: nature_people
- title: Lorem title
  description: Lorem description 
  icon:
    type: image
    image_path: /uploads/my-icon.png
    alt: An example icon
- title: Lorem title
  description: Lorem description 
  icon:
    type: svg
    value: >-
      <svg>
        <!-- The SVG elements -->
      </svg>
```

Then use conditionals in your template:

```
{% for item in site.data.example %}
  {% if item.icon.type == 'icon' %}
    <i class="material-icons">{{ item.icon.name }}</span>
  {% elsif item.icon.type == 'image' %}
    <img src="{{ item.icon.image_path }}" alt="{{ item.icon.alt }}">
  {% else %}
    {{ item.icon.value }}
  {% end %}

  <h3>{{ item.title }}</h3>
  <p>{{ item.description</p>
{% endfor %}
```

This does assume that icon is always set.

Comment: I will try this. I tried putting svg code into one of the data file rows, but it didnt work. Does your example work because it is specifically set as "value?" Does it work because it is nested within "icon"? Does it work because of both used in tandem?

Comment: Most likely, you'll need to quote the value properly so it's valid YAML. If it is, the problem could be when you are using the value. Hard to know without seeing it. The nesting and names used don't affect it outside of referencing the value from your template.

Comment: Does the SVG code in the YAML file have to be all in one line in order for the YAML file to function properly in Jekyll?

Comment: You could put it all on one line if you want - I've changed the example to demonstrate one format for multiline YAML values. There's a fair bit more to it though - likely better for a separate question. Here's a site that has a interactive demo of each format: https://yaml-multiline.info/